# Using Volley GET method to insert in database with Node js API

Tags: android, node.js, android-volley

i am actually using volley to insert into database with a Node js webservice  . 
this is my Node js code :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var url = require('url');
router.get('/',function (req,res,next) {
    var queryData = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var config = {
        host : 'localhost',
        user : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'travelmatedb'
    }
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
    connection.connect();
    connection.query("INSERT INTO feedback (stars,description) VALUES ('"+queryData.stars+ "', '"+queryData.description+ "')",
        function(err,rows,fields){
       if (!err){
           var signup = {msg:"thanks , feedback added"}
           res.send(signup);
    }
    else
    {
        var error = {msg:"error cannot execute query"}
        res.send(err);
    }
});
    connection.end();
});
module.exports = router;
```

and this is my android code  :

```
                String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/addfeedback?stars="+String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating()+"&description="+description.getText().toString());
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.GET,
                        URL,
                        null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                System.out.println("trip added");
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.e("Rest Response",error.toString());
                            }
                        }
                );


                requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
```

it's already  inserting in database correctly but my question is that safe inserting , updating or deleting using GET method in volley ? it's not supposed to be POST method ? then if it should be using POST method why it's working with GET method ? does this have any side effects when deploying the app ?

i am a newbie here so excuse my lack of experience and thank you all .

Comment: Be very careful with user supplied Data. In this case the QueryString; you are super open to SQL Injection! Take a look at Prepared Statements in MySQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: @GavinHarris how can i avoid SQL injection and keep using GET method ?

Comment: Why do you need to use GET method? GET should run a SELECT, not INSERT

Comment: i am actually new to android developement and node js i stil did not find a working syntax with POST .

Comment: In any case, Nodejs has prepared statements and it should be documented somewhere on the mysql npm module

Comment: `Request.Method.GET` should be `Request.Method.POST` and `router.post('/'`... Both of which are documented in Volley and ExpressJS documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at your NodeJS / Express module, I'm no expert, but I would look at reworking something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var url = require('url');

//TODO: Get these parameters from process.env.XXXX
var config = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'travelmatedb'
}
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool(config);

var INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO feedback (stars, description) VALUES (:stars, :desc)";

// Changed to accept a POST request, respect RESTFul
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var queryData = req.query; // Express already parses the Query Params into the request.query object

  //TODO: Validate that the supplied Parameters are there

  if (!req.query.stars) {
    return res.status(400).json({msg: "`stars` is required"});
  }

  pool.query(
    INSERT_SQL, {
      "stars": queryData.stars,
      "desc": queryData.description
    },
    function (err, rows, fields) {
      if (!err) {
        var signup = {
          msg: "thanks , feedback added"
        }
        res.json(signup);
      } else {
        var error = {
          msg: "error cannot execute query"
        }
        console.log(err.message, err); //Print out that actual error
        res.status(500).json(error);
      }
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections

Comment: sir please can you rework the android volley part also and adapt it to a Volley POST request ? so i can accept your answer and upvote it .

Comment: As mentioned in the Comments to your Question, I have edited the answer above to Listen for a POST request, so the Volley change would be to change `Request.Method.GET` to `Request.Method.POST`; the rest should stay same (you are not using a Request body etc)

Comment: i changed  GET with  POST as you mentioned and i got an error : com.android.volley.ClientError